# Error While implementing Reactive Redis in the part of Deserialization

Tags: redis, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, spring-data-redis, spring-data-redis-reactive

```
Could not read JSON: Cannot construct instance of reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"@class":"reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime","scanAvailable":true}"; line: 1, column: 50]
This error occured while implementing Reactive Redis. The value is stored in the redis but could not deserialize it. The value stored in redis as: {"@class":"reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime","scanAvailable":true}
```

I am using spring annotation @Cachable for the operation

I have tried using custom serializer/deserializer but it also didnot work.